# How to write generic omit function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
function omit<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, okeys: P[]) {
    return (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).reduce((newObj, key)=> {
        for (const filKey of okeys) {
            if (filKey != key) {
                newObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }, {} as Omit<T,P>)
}
```

I want to omit the few properties from obj

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a generic function, just write e.g.:

```js
const { omit1, omit2, ...filtered } = source
```

`filtered` will contain all the properties of `source` except `omit1` and `omit2`.

If you have the keys as array of string, you could go with something like this:

```js
function omit<T extends object, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, okeys: P[]): Omit<T, P> {
  const ret = { ...obj }
  okeys.forEach((key) => delete ret[key])
  return ret
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export function omit<T extends Object, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...omitkeys: P[]): Omit<T, P> {
    return (Object.keys(obj)).reduce((newObj, key) => {
        for (const omitKey of omitkeys) {
            if (omitKey != key) {
                newObj[key as Exclude<keyof T, P>] = obj[key as Exclude<keyof T, P>];
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }, {} as Omit<T, P>)
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but could do with an explanation or rationale as to why you have written this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to filter out the properties of the object. It will make typing less cumbersome also. You will only need a cast for end result :

```
function omit2<T extends {}, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, okeys: P[]): Omit<T, P> {
  const b = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, _]) => !okeys.includes(k as P)))
  return b as Omit<T, P>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/LAKFDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aACZBbR8BMAeAFTQFMAPeE6AEwGc0BvAXwBo0AFUiqutAaxIBPZODSEAfAApkAIwBWALjFtkAwbSXsA2gF0AlEoDy2eETbtxjUGjSxUteGhloAvGkPySCAHTgATlgAotDwfogktJIecl7w3lSh4ZGycnq+iAA2lH6Sklp8bAD6+q6WAISqQrTeiHAZkNQRknxoAIb07Hpd1mh+JPCQfujO7e4mZhziANygTKCgdtAOtq6MbUoARK0bbDKbMju2SgxoZJuCG2hMVzNgd4vLfqtYOLiSsGxaWzsbB-qgQA)

Comment: export function omit<T extends object, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...omitkeys: P[]): Omit<T, P>{
    return (Object.keys(obj)).reduce((newobj, key) => {
        for (const omitkey of omitkeys) {
            if (omitkey != key) {
                newobj[key as Exclude<keyof T, P>] = obj[key as Exclude<keyof T,P>];
            }
        }
        return newobj;
    }, {} as Omit<T,P>)
}